# JQuery: show dialog in different page after submit data

Tags: jquery, dialog, messagebox

For example, i have a computer as a server. And i have 3 client PC.

i want after input some data, the data which have submitted can show as Dialog. And of course this dialog can appear in another page if each user open some page. This dialog's function is as information message.

could i do this use JQuery? or do you have another advice? is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'webpage_to_check',
        data: { },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        // You can do something before posting data.
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        var Response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        if ((XMLHttpRequest.responseText == 'false') || (Response.Status == false)) {
            // FAIL
        }
        else {
            // SUCCESS
            $('#myDialog').dialog("open");
        }
        }
    }); 
});
```

which defines a dialog a calls a page of yours (GET or POST) and read the informations returned. I've defined a JSON answer but you use XML or pure text.
Second option is to do the same on each page but with something like a polling system so your javascript checks every X seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });


    function ScheduledAction(func, times, interval) {
        var ID = setInterval(function() {
            if (times > -1) {
                if (--times <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(ID);
                }
            }
            func();
        }, interval);
    }

    function CheckStatus()
    {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'webpage_to_check',
        data: { },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
        // You can do something before posting data.
        },
        complete: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
        var Response = $.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
        if ((XMLHttpRequest.responseText == 'false') || (Response.Status == false)) {
            // FAIL
        }
        else {
            // SUCCESS
            $('#myDialog').dialog("open");
        }
        }
    }); 
    }

    ScheduledAction(CheckStatus, -1, 30);

});
```

Comment: i want like SO did, on any page that we are open, there will be show some notification.

Comment: I think I don't really get what you mean. if you don't want your check to be scheduled at intervals you should use the first script.That is triggered every time a page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since server-push isn't ready for the web yet, the pages on which you want the dialog box to appear will need to poll the server to see if the data has arrived (just like StackOverflow polls when you're writing an answer to see if other answers have been posted).

You do that with [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) *(that's a link)*, and then show the dialog box either with your own code, or (recommended) using your favorite dialog-box plug-in for jQuery (such as [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)).

Comment: have you some tutorials to do this?